# Fully clone your system from a SATA device to a NVMe device

Tags: boot, ssd, grub, clonezilla, nvme

I am working on a laptop with a 500 GB SSD, dual booting on Windows and Ubuntu.

I recently bought a Samsung 960 EVO m.2 NVMe 500 GB SSD and installed it successfully. However, given the faster interface provided by NVMe compared to SATA/AHCI, I'd like to move my current systems to the NVMe SSD.

Reasonably enough, I used CloneZilla (You should (as always) get the latest stable release, as NVMe interfaced disks aren't recognized on older versions, that often come packaged with USB boot disk creating software such as lili USB creator) and cloned all the content from my SATA SSD to my NVMe SSD. As soon as I'll be able to boot on the NVMe SSD, i'll format the SATA SSD and use it as storage.

I had to work a lot with the UEFI before I was able to have the NVMe SSD available in the boot options. However, I did not have to mod my BIOS. It seems that it started to appear in the boot options as soon as I had a bootmgr on my NVMe SSD, that CloneZilla had cloned.

However, as you could expect, I got the same issue as [I can boot from a clone, but only when the original drive isn't plugged in](https://superuser.com/questions/1298164/i-can-boot-from-a-clone-but-only-when-the-original-drive-isnt-plugged-in) and I expected it.

I didn't change the drive's unique identifier yet, but I have a few concerns before I  do it:

1) Since CloneZilla cloned all of the configuration of GRUB, if I boot on the GRUB of the NVMe SSD, Iget the GRUB, but of course, it still lists sda1 instead of nvme0n1p1, so it will boot on the SATA SSD. Would reinstalling GRUB solve this problem, or do I have a high risk of losing possibility to boot? I'd say that as long as I keep the data on both disks, installing GRUB would have GRUB list a) Ubuntu on /dev/nvme0n1p1 b) Windows boot manager on /dev/nvme0n1p2 c) Ubuntu on /dev/sda1 d) Windows boot manager on /dev/sda2

2) when I override the boot order to boot on Windows boot manager on the NVMe SSD, Windows doesn't boot, it gets stuck on the loading screen, without ever failing, just stuck. Would you think that is the consequence of trying to boot on a newer disk with the same drive ID as the old one (as [The post that I mentioned earlier](https://superuser.com/questions/1298164/i-can-boot-from-a-clone-but-only-when-the-original-drive-isnt-plugged-in) would suggest).
Would changing the drive's id solve this problem?

I know that all of this seems overly cautious, and that it seems like it wouldn't cost me much to try the solutions I've listed, but I'd rather be sure that I can go through and provide feedback to other users with the same issue than just blindly go into it without being entirely sure that it is safe.

Comment: Yes it's all very safe.  Clonezilla has fixed your concerns with clonezilla driver support to be able to see, read and write from and between your /dev/nvme0n1 and /dev/sda drives.  download the latest iso/usb boot medium from their website.