# Can't boot PC after cloning HDD to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, clone, migration

Yesterday I cloned the full contents of my HDD (including a Windows and a Ubuntu partition) to my new SSD (Samsung 860 EVO). I can now successfully boot into Ubuntu from the SSD, but when trying to boot into Windows (when my HDD is not connected anymore), I get a blue screen displaying "your pc/device needs to be repaired". I used Macrium Reflect for the clone.

Here is an image from Macrium reflect of the current situation:

[image: macrium reflect]

And here is an image of the Disk Management tool:

[image: disk management]

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Was the HDD still connected during your _first_ Windows boot after cloning?

Comment: @user1686 Yes, is this a problem?

Comment: Yes, because your HDD and your SSD now have the same ID (as they are cloned) so Windows can't differentiate between them. Disconnect the HDD and test it again. To make each disk unique again see https://superuser.com/questions/1250123/cloned-disk-duplicate-disk-signature-how-to-resolve/1250177

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, you must have the old HDD *disconnected* the first time you boot Windows after cloning.

It seems that Windows remembers volume letter assignments based on several different identifiers, but mainly the hardware ID (model/serial number).

- If you boot with just the new disk connected, it'll see that the same partition is now on a different device and automatically update the volume assignments for the new hardware ID.
- But if you boot with both disks connected, Windows will actually *continue using the old disk* because it finds an exact match for the old hardware ID it remembers. Even if you start the bootloader from the new disk, it'll still think that "C:" is on the old one.

I would suggest re-cloning the disk again (half a TB won't hurt an EVO), then immediately disconnecting the old disk before trying to boot Windows.

(It should be fine to connect the old disk later, even with its contents intact. It's of course okay to connect it after deleting the old Windows partition.)

Comment: Thank you, re-doing the cloning and then detaching the HDD before booting up again did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience, but i used Active Disk Manager and it worked

Link for the Software:

https://www.disk-image.com/index.html

When you open the software, you need to select "Copy Disk to Disk" Option.